# MediaElement - Video Gets out of Sync with Audio - WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mediaelement, mediastreamsource

I am using MediaElement in my wp7 project which plays the video from online stream (mp4 format)

Things seems working but sometimes I noticed that Video gets a bit quick like playing in fast mode for a while and that makes video a bit ahead of Audio.

So whats the reason, Should I use MediaStreamSource or should I use SmoothMediaElement?

I thought it might be due to there are some threads which are updating UI using "Dispatcher.BeginInvoke" so I tried stopping all of them but problem remains there so it can be due to slow network or something but it shouldn't be doing like this. :(

Please help.